# Load file into a table and then update the last entered row

Tags: php, mysql, lampp

MySQL : Here is structure of my table BugInfo. Serial # field is Auto INcrement and Primary.

```
    Serial# | BugID    | Submittername  |   Title         | Status | Description |
       1    |  ABc1234 |   John Michael | S/W not behaving| New    | Some text
       2    |  XYZ1234 |   Carl Paul    | S/W not behaving| New    | Some text
```

The first COL being Auto Increment. What i would like to do insert the first 5 and then update the Description column (6th) with data.

The data for the first 5 Cols and the 6th (description) are in Seperate files. I need to add them in the same query.

Right now i do this, but this is a simple and a straight forward, but i am getting stumped in getting the current serial # and update that Row with the "Description"

```
$sql="LOAD DATA INFILE '/opt/sw1/UCBT/UCBTexport/UCBTexport.txt'INTO TABLE BugInfo FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ( BugID, Submittername, Title, Status)";
```

please note, i would like do the insert from two separate files. Really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: for above task you can use php/java

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, I need help with the MySQL query.